# Setting up staging environment with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, elixir

I've been able to set up a production environment with the App Engine but now I want to consider setting up a staging environment but this seems harder than I've expected.

To set up the prod env I needed to create an `app.yaml` file:

```
env: flex
runtime: gs://elixir-runtime/elixir.yaml
runtime_config:
    release_app: statcasters
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: statcasters:us-central1:statcastersproduction
```

This makes sense and is super easy but what about a staging env? How do I tell the app engine to deploy a different app? I'm not finding really any good documentation of this anywhere.

Comment: App Engine Standard does not know about "Staging", "Production", etc. You could use different service names. I use different projects. One project for Development, another for Testing, another for Production. This keeps everything the same (except for the deployment project ID) and also provides for IAM user isolation.

Comment: I agree with using different projects. Clear segregation of IAM and environments.

Answer (score 12):

I use the default `app.yaml` file to deploy to prod, and a separate `app.staging.yaml` file for staging.

To deploy to prod, I just run the normal deploy pointing to my prod project:

```sh
gcloud app deploy --project [prod-project-name]
```

To deploy to staging, I point to a separate staging project:

```sh
gcloud app deploy app.staging.yaml --project [staging-project-name]
```

Inside `app.yaml`, I use a environment variable  to set the environment, eg:

```
env_variables:
  APP_ENV: "production"
```